# Asp.Net Core async lazy initialization per request

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, thread-safety, lazy-initialization

For many endpoints in our multi-tenant Asp.Net Core 2.2 web app, we need to get some tenant information from our database on a per-request basis (using an asynchronous database call), then reuse that information from various points in the request pipeline as required without having to make a database call each time. That is, we'd like something like a lazy async property on a per-request basis.

Based on the various docs I've read, instances of **scoped** services are only ever accessed by one thread at a time (the thread processing the request). So, I believe this means that I should be able to safely do something like the following:

```
// Registered as scoped in the DI container
public class TenantInfoRetriever : ITenantInfoRetriever
{
    private TenantInfo _tenantInfo;
    private bool _initialized;

    public async Task<TenantInfo> GetAsync()
    {
        // This code is obviously not thread safe, which is why it's important that no two threads are running here at the same time.
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            _tenantInfo = await GetTenantInfoAsync(); // this might actually legitimately return null, hence the need for the separate property "_initialized"
            _initialized = true;
        }
        return _tenantInfo;
    }

    private async Task<TenantInfo> GetTenantInfoAsync()
    {
        return await DoDatabaseCallToGetTenantInfo(); // of course this would use an injected EfContext instance (scoped service)
    }
}
```

To the best of my knowledge this should work because scoped services don't need to be thread-safe.

**My question:** are my assumptions here correct, or am I perhaps missing something important?

Comment: _Based on the various docs I've read, instances of scoped services are only ever accessed by one thread at a time (the thread processing the request)._ Is not exactly correct, since when you await an operation, the thread is returned to the thread pool and when it resumes one free thread from the thread pool will be picked up. Its not necessary the **exact same thread** which started it. But yes, there won't be two threads accessing it at the **same time**. But whats your issue with it? If you worry it be accessed, do a double lock pattern

Comment: Alternatively use `AsyncLazy<T>` (see [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asynclazyt/)). (Removed the previous link, since it was referencing to visualstudio-ts library which shouldn't be used outside of Visual Studio Extension packages

Comment: Thanks @Tseng. I guess I'd prefer to keep things simple, i.e. without having to worry about locking. Based on what you've said, no two threads will be accessing an instance of this service concurrently, so this suggests to me that locking isn't necessary. Similarly, the AsyncLazy approach seems designed to be for multi-thread scenarios, so I'm thinking it's a bit overkill. My question was mainly meant to make sure I'm not overlooking something critical before I go ahead with my simple approach. If you're interested in mapping your comments to an answer I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on the various docs I've read, instances of scoped services are only ever accessed by one thread at a time (the thread processing the request).

That's not exactly correct. When you await an operation, the thread is returned to the thread pool and when the async operation resumes, one free thread from the thread pool will be picked up. 
Its not necessary the exact same thread which started it.

But yes, there won't be two threads accessing it **at the same time** when its scoped -  that is from ASP.NET Core side.

Of course, you need to take precautions of your own code too.
If you spin up two tasks / threads and run them at the same time, then it still possible for it to be accessed at the same time.

If you worry it be accessed, do a double-check lock pattern (with volatile field) or locking on a mutex (object that isn't the value you modify) or use `AsyncLazy<T>`, i.e. from [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asynclazyt/).

Examples (from https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/CSHARP/Double-checked+lock+is+not+thread-safe)

Example 1:

```
string name;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        lock (mutex)    // GOOD: Thread-safe
        {
            if (name == null)
                name = LoadNameFromDatabase();
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
volatile string name;    // GOOD: Thread-safe

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            lock (mutex)
            {
                if (name == null)
                    name = LoadNameFromDatabase();
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```